# Can I get a quality gate to fail if mutation coverage is not high enough?

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, mutation-testing

We are using the default 'SonarQube way' quality gate, which has a 'Mutations Coverage' setting, however this does not seem to cause the gate to fail.

For example, I have a small test project that does not have enough mutation coverage, and reports this as a code smell:

```
3 more mutants need to be covered by unit tests to reach the minimum threshold of 65% mutant coverage
```

This comes from a FindBugs quality profile. Is it possible also to fail a quality gate?

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the quality gate (SonarQube way) by adding a rule, that errors (or warns) if the Mutation coverage is "less than" 65